# How do you detect keystrokes in video games with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, keystroke

I am trying to develop a program in which I log whenever I press certain keys in video games(eg. CS:GO), so that I may study data concerning my most pressed keys, ratios between keystrokes, and whatnot. I have developed the following function:

```
def key_down(key):
        state = win32api.GetKeyState(ord(key))
        if state != 0 and state != 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

However, when I try to use this function in game(I have windows OS), it is unable to detect keystrokes for any given key. Is there a viable solution to this dilema?

Comment: Use the module pygame it can easily detect a keystroke

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pygame/ documeantation link

Comment: https://youtu.be/FfWpgLFMI7w turotorial link

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that the problem is intrinsic to the way GetKeyState works.

By the way, your code block could be written a bit more concisely as follows:

```
def key_down(key):
    state = win32api.GetKeyState(ord(key))
    return state not in {0, 1}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer worth considering, but I don’t think that this would solve my problem. Being currently away from home, I can’t provide any more media, but the code seemed to run just fine outside of any video game I opened: when I hit a key, it was logged. However, it seems as if the fact that I had a video game opened as my foreground application somehow affected the performance of the code. Is there any reason why that might be? Thank you for the code block suggestion.

Comment: The documentation for [GetKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) explains, why it cannot be used: *"The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue."* It won't observe the key state in context of another thread or process. That aside, sampling is always wrong. You'll want to respond to events instead, a paradigm that's hard to teach to Python developers. Regardless, pick either a low-level keyboard hook or go with Raw Input.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the correction, I deleted my comment in light of this new info. It's clear that you know more about WinAPI and C++ than I do. But, (1) why do you say it's hard to teach Python developers about responding to events? (2) What are some nice resources for learning WinAPI?

Comment: `1` Just an observation. As I recall, I haven't seen a *single* proposed answer to a Python question that would go as far as acknowledging the existence of an event-based solution. `2` You're going to have to learn C. When done you'll find lots of resources, like [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows). Despite the title it's perfectly sufficient to know C. But C you must absolutely know before you can learn the Windows API.